# php5-sqlite shows me nothing

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu

The following code should display a message but shows me nothing (neither on the screen, nor in the source code). Any idea why this may be?

```
<?php
   try
   {   
      //create or open the database
      $database = new SQLiteDatabase('myDatabase.sqlite', 0666, $error);
      echo 'that works';
   }   
   catch(Exception $e) 
   {   
      die('that doesnt: '.$error);
   }
```

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 11 2012
  02:17:16)

phpinfo() shows me the following:

- ...
- Additional .ini files parsed: ...
  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/sqlite.ini, ...
- PDO drivers  mysql, sqlite
- SQLite Library   3.7.7
- ...

SQLite was installed that way:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabase` is not a valid class name, at least not in this extension.

You're looking for [`Sqlite3`](http://php.net/class.sqlite3):

```
$db = new Sqlite3('myDatabase.sqlite');
```

Since the class is undefined, it's provoking a fatal error, and you probably don't see anything because of either your `error_reporting` level or `display_errors` setting.